# Exactly what triggers the release of Melatonin?

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles, sleep-deprivation, melatonin

I work nights and I know it's terrible for the health (circadian rhythm) but what can you do, I'm stuck and can't get another job.  I'm not taking any melatonin, because I'm skeptical of taking hormones as being good for me.  I do have lots of issues sleeping, sometimes 3 hours sometimes 4 hours a day, feeling nauseous, temperature swings, headaches, mood swings, yada yada.

Anyways, I know the lack of sunlight triggers the release of melatonin and when the sun rises, melatonin release decreases. Is the trigger though the eyes or through the skin?  I want to understand exactly how I can naturally trigger melatonin as possible.  I can only cover up so much sun that enters my apartment, but wondering if beyond wearing an eyemask, I should cover my skin as well.

Please save me the spiel on the health effects of sleeping during the day as it'll just stress me out and I can't do anything about it.   I'm trying to reduce as many other stressors as I can.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Melatonin synthesis and secretion (pineal gland) is enhanced by darkness and inhibited by light (photons).

[image: Diagram of the major controlling mechanisms of melatonin release.]

*DOI: 10.1530/ror.0.0030013  PMID: 9509985*

Comment: Thanks.  So shut my eyes as tightly as I can ha